How can I dynamically create a RichTextArea field in Salesforce using the Metadata API?
I'm developing an application in Salesforce that needs to automatically create a custom object during installation, and this object should include a RichTextArea field.
I'm using jsforce to handle dynamic object and field creation, but I'm encountering the error: 'RichTextArea' is not a valid value for the enum 'FieldType'.
Is there any way to programmatically create a RichTextArea field using the Metadata API, Tooling API, or any other alternative?
I would appreciate any suggestions or implementation examples.
      ```{
        fullName: "body__c",
        label: "Body",
        type: "RichTextArea",
      },```


Based on the documentation, I'm guessing you  want to set type = html but also isHtmlFormatted = true

From my org, a CustomField for a RTF looks like this:
<fields xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <fullName>Log_RTF__c</fullName>
  <description>some text</description>
  <label>Log</label>
  <length>32768</length>
  <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
  <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
  <type>Html</type>
  <visibleLines>10</visibleLines>
</fields>

Valid values for Type are documented in the MD API Reference doc
Indicates the type of a custom field. Valid values are:
Address (beta)
AutoNumber
Lookup
MasterDetail
MetadataRelationship
Checkbox
Currency
Date
DateTime
Email
EncryptedText
ExternalLookup
IndirectLookup
Number[1]
Percent
Phone
Picklist
MultiselectPicklist
Summary
Text
TextArea
LongTextArea
Url
Hierarchy
File
Html
Location (use for geolocation fields)
Time

[1] A Number custom field is internally represented as a field of type double. Setting the scale of the Number field to 0 gives you a double that behaves like an int.
